# Thread send mail in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, email

I'am new in ruby and i want to send mail every days at 9PM with data so any ideas to do this in ruby ( Thread )
this my code to send mail :

```
message = <<MESSAGE_END
From: TEST <test@test.com>
To: A Test User <tes2t@test.com>
Subject:  Feedback mail status reminder

This is a test e-mail message.
MESSAGE_END

Net::SMTP.start('localhost') do |smtp|
  smtp.send_message message, 'test@test.com',
                         'test2@test.com'
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sidekiq is also a better option to do it. You can run your job at specific timings and it will run using [redis](http://redis.io/) server in the backgorund.

Create Workers in `'app/'` folder and call it from the `controller`/`Model` method. Setup an initializer file `sidekiq.rb` to specify the Redis queue for all environments to boot up.

Check the below given links for reference.

1. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq
2. http://sidekiq.org/
3. http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the gem 'whenever', like this:

```
every :day, :at => '12:00am' do
```

runner "AAA.xxx"
end

and your code:

```
message = <<MESSAGE_END
```

From: TEST 
To: A Test User 
Subject:  Feedback mail status reminder

This is a test e-mail message.
MESSAGE_END

as a method xxx

Comment: so, in my method 
def test
every :day, :at => '12:00am' do
send_email "test@test.com", :body => "This is a test"
end
end 
???????
thanks

Answer (score 0):

In ruby on rails, maybe you can use rufus-scheduler. Create a rb file under config\initializers. Add some code like:

```
scheduler.cron '0 21 * * *' do
    # call your function method or implment the function
end
```

For more detail, please refer to [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler)

Comment: LoadError: no such file to load -- rufus-scheduler, any ideas please
thanks

Comment: seems like the LoadError is getting addressed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096449/no-such-file-to-load-rufus-scheduler