# No such file to load -- rufus-scheduler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby, rufus-scheduler

I'am developing a plugin in redmine how send mail every days , so i install rufus-scheduler 
and in my Gemfile i add this line

```
gem "rufus-scheduler "
```

and also i install the gem

```
sudo gem install rufus-scheduler --source http://gemcutter.org
```

and in my redmine/plugins/latest-issues-redmine-plugin/lib/latest_issues/view_hook_listener.rb i do this

```
class LatestIssuesViewHookListener < Redmine::Hook::ViewListener

    require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../../app/models/latest_issues_setup')
    require 'net/smtp'
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'rufus-scheduler

def load_issues   
 scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new   
 scheduler.every '1h' do
send_email "test@test.com", :body => html
  end
end
end
```

Any ideas for this error ?

Thanks

Comment: 1: Which Ruby version? 2: Are you using rvm?

Comment: jruby 1.7.10 (1.9.3p392) 2014-01-09 c4ecd6b on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_51-mockbuild_2014_01_10_10_19-b00 [linux-amd64] And Rails 3.2.16

Comment: what do you mean by "i do this in my code"? Do you mean a) you try that as a standalone script or b) I blindly paste that in my rails controller... ?

Comment: i just past in my controller

Comment: Warning: it's dangerous to start a rufus-scheduler for each HTTP request hitting your view listener. Each scheduler gets its own thread, you'll end up with the Ruby process overwhelmed with unused schedulers. The better way is to start the scheduler somewhere in config/initializers/ and then schedule from the controller/listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo gem install rufus-scheduler --source http://gemcutter.org
```

installs rubygems via the "gem" command, which, usually, points to the "system" Ruby which is, usually again, not JRuby.

You could probably do

```
jruby -S gem install rufus-scheduler
```

to install the gem in the JRuby load path.

Answer (score 3):

you write in your Gemfile

```
gem "rufus-scheduler "
```

shouldn't it be

```
gem "rufus-scheduler"
```

instead?

After adding the line, you'd have to run

```
bundle install
```

to let Bundler grab the rufus-scheduler gem (and update the Gemfile.lock file).

IIRC, upon starting the Rails application, Bundler should already have complained about not having rufus-scheduler around. That should have happened before the LoadError. So, are you starting the Rails app with Bundler? (How do you start it anyway?)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
require 'rubygems' # tell ruby that you're using rubygems
require 'rufus-scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new # rufus-scheduler 3.0 style

scheduler.in '5s' do
  puts "order ristretto"
end
scheduler.every '10s' do
  puts "I feel like drinking coffee"
end

#scheduler.join
```

You seem to follow an old tutorial. The current readme for rufus-scheduler is at https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler

Comment: hi jmettraux, i try youre code and refer to this tutorial https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler and istill have this LoadError: No such file to load -- rufus-scheduler, thanks

Comment: LoadError means that Ruby cannot find the "rufus-scheduler" code in its load path. How do you manage your dependencies? Try to explain in your question (by editing the question) so we don't waste time in those tiny comments...